# Javascript Time limit exceeded

Tags: javascript, performance, object, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a dynamic programming problem on LeetCode using an object (obj) as a cache, but I am encountering a 'time limit exceeded' error if I initialize the object like this:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var canPartition = function(nums) {
    var sum = nums.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  return accumulator + currentValue
},0);
console.log(sum/ 2)

    if(sum % 2 === 0) {
       return checkIfPart(0, Number(sum/2), nums, {})
    }
    return false
};

var checkIfPart  = function(currentIndex, currentWeight, nums, obj) {
    if (obj && currentIndex in obj  && currentWeight in obj[currentIndex]) {
        return  obj[currentIndex][currentWeight]
    }
    if (currentWeight === 0) {
        return true
    }
    if (currentIndex >= nums.length || currentWeight < 0) {
        return false
    }
   console.log(nums[currentIndex])
    let put = checkIfPart(currentIndex + 1, currentWeight - nums[currentIndex], nums, obj)
    let notPut = checkIfPart(currentIndex+ 1, currentWeight, nums, obj)
    if (!obj[currentIndex]) {
        obj[currentIndex] = {}
    }
    obj[currentIndex][currentWeight] =  put || notPut
    return put || notPut
}
```

However, if I initialize it as follows:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var canPartition = function(nums) {
//     var sum = nums.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
//   return accumulator + currentValue
// },0);
const n =nums.length
 let sum = 0
 for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    if(sum % 2 === 0) {
       
        var obj = new Array(n+1).fill(-1).map(() => new Array(sum/2+1).fill(-1));
       return checkIfPart(0, Number(sum/2), nums, obj)
    }
    return false
};

var checkIfPart  = function(currentIndex, currentWeight, nums, obj) {
    if (obj[currentIndex][currentWeight] != -1) {
        return  obj[currentIndex][currentWeight]
    }
    if (currentWeight === 0) {
        return true
    }
    if (currentIndex >= nums.length || currentWeight < 0) {
        return false
    }
    let put = checkIfPart(currentIndex + 1, currentWeight - nums[currentIndex], nums, obj)
    let notPut = checkIfPart(currentIndex+ 1, currentWeight, nums, obj)
   
    obj[currentIndex][currentWeight] =  put || notPut
    return put || notPut
}
```

My code is accepted. So, my question is, what is wrong with the first approach? Whenever I try to do something like this:

```
if (obj && currentIndex in obj  && currentWeight in obj[currentIndex]) {
        return  obj[currentIndex][currentWeight]
    }
```

I am getting a 'time limit exceeded' error. Can anyone please help me understand the issue?"
Here's the link to the problem
[enter link description here](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/description/)

Comment: Array access is a lot faster than object access (offset computation is simple addition vs hash lookup which involves a bunch of math and a possible linked list walk), for one. For two, reallocations are avoided with the up-front allocated array approach. Cache locality may be better with the array version. Providing a link to the problem helps so people can run your code and understand what you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have provided the link

Comment: Aren't objects are supposed to store the elements to find them in o(1)?

Comment: Time complexity is different than efficiency. Sure, hash lookups are amortized constant time (worst case O(n)), but `for (let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {}` is also O(1). Some O(1) algorithms have a larger constant factor than others, as is the case here. Using `in` plus an indexing operation twice is 4 hash lookups.

Comment: You can try writing large test cases and benchmarking the two algorithms. Also, remove all `console.log`s--they're slow.